# How to get accurate lat and long of current location in react native

Tags: react-native, geolocation

I want to get `latitude`, `longitude` of my current location. For that, I have installed [react-native-geolocation](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-geolocation) and implement it according to its document. But it is giving the wrong `latitude`, `longitude`. Same goes for [react-native-geolocation-service](https://github.com/Agontuk/react-native-geolocation-service).

Here the code I tried

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Alert } from 'react-native';
import Geolocation from '@react-native-community/geolocation';

export default class GeolocationExample extends React.Component {
  state = {
    latitude: 'unknown',
    longitude: 'unknown',
  };

  componentDidMount() {

   Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      position => {
        const latitude = JSON.stringify(position.coords.latitude);
        const longitude = JSON.stringify(position.coords.longitude);
        this.setState({ latitude, longitude });
      },
      error => Alert.alert('Error', JSON.stringify(error)),
      { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 },
    );
  }

  render() {
    const { latitude, longitude } = this.state;
    console.log(latitude, longitude);

    return (
      <View>
        <Text>
          <Text style={styles.title}>latitude: </Text>
          {this.state.latitude}
        </Text>
        <Text>
          <Text style={styles.title}>longitude: </Text>
          {this.state.longitude}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-get-location. This gets accurate location for the reactnative app

Comment: Kindly add context to any links so your Answer is self contained, meaning the answer needs to be here in the Answer itself. See ["Provide context for links"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). It would be preferable if you could answer the Question in your own words here and link only as a reference. How does it work? How is it used? Show how it answers the Question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/timfpark/react-native-location.

It has option Google Fused Location api on android which is Google recommenced. You have to add following modules in you app level build.gradle file

implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1"

implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0"

You can set "desiredAccuracy" to "highAccuracy" for android & for ios "best"